# sat or was sitting?

Tags: past-tense, past-continuous

What's the difference between "sat" and "was sitting" in the following? Are they interchangeable?

> Mary sat on the bench, looking at George.

> Mary was sitting on the bench, looking at George.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They may mean the same, but *was sitting* is unambiguously continuous.

*Mary sat ...* could mean that she was standing, looking at George, but suddenly took a seated position.